# Can't find call record option in windows 10 phone, does that depend on Country/Region?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calls

I am using windows 10 phone and unable to find the call record option.

**Settings->System->Phone**
In phone settings page there should be a default call record option but unfortunately it does not exist.

**Windows 10 OS**

- Version : 1607
- Build : 10.0.14393.1066

Comment: What's the name of your phone model?

Comment: I am using Lumia 535

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only devices which shipped with W10 mobile can support Call Recording.
Your device had W8 originally so it does not have call recording capabilities.